# Copy many tables in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, regex

I want to copy many tables with similar names but different prefixes. I want the tables with the wp_ prefix to go into their corresponding tables with the shop_ prefix.

In other words, I want to do *something* like this:

```
insert into shop_wpsc_*
select * from wp_wpsc_*
```

How would **you** do this?

Comment: Wich kind of database system?

Comment: What database are you running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on OMG Ponies' answer a bit, you can use the data dictionary and write a SQL to write the SQL's. For example, in Oracle, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT 'insert into shop_wpsc_' || SUBSTR(table_name,9) || ' select * from ' || table_name || ';'
FROM all_tables
WHERE table_name LIKE 'WP_SPSC%'
```

This will generate a series of SQL statements you can run as a single script. Like OMG Ponies' pointed out though, the syntax will vary depending on what DB vendor you are using (e.g. `all_tables` is Oracle specific).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. This seems like the best method. Unfortunately I don't have access to the INFORMATION_SCHEMA table in the MySQL db. Looks like I'll have to do this in Vim.

Answer (score 3):

SQL doesn't allow wildcarding table names - the only way to do this is to loop through a list of tables (via the ANSI INFORMATION_SCHEMA/INFORMATION_SCHEMAS) while using dynamic SQL.

Dynamic SQL is different for every database vendor...

### Update

MySQL?  Why didn't you say so in the first place...

MySQL's dynamic SQL is called "Prepared Statements" - [this is my fav link](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/11/mysql-5-prepared-statement-syntax-and.html) for it besides the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html).  There're numerous questions on SO about operations on all the tables in a MySQL database - just need to tweak the WHERE clause to get the table names you want.

You'll want to do this from within a [MySQL stored procedure](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx)...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by combining multiple statements into a single prepared statement -- try doing this:

```
SELECT @sql_text := GROUP_CONCAT(
                              CONCAT('insert into shop_wpsc_',
                                      SUBSTRING(table_name, 9),
                                      ' select * from ', table_name, ';'), ' ')
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 WHERE table_schema = 'example'
   AND table_name LIKE 'wp_wpsc_%';

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;

EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: @Tom: Using @[username] makes it turn up in my msgs; I'm hoping to remember to test this tomorrow.

Comment: @OMG Ponies thanks for the tip. Let me know how the test works out.

Comment: @Tom: I updated your answer with what didn't cause a syntax error for me on MySQL 5.1.x within a stored procedure.

Comment: @OMG Ponies thanks for your efforts -- I'm glad to see that this approach can be made to work.

Answer (score 0):

First I would select all tables from the catalog views (the name of those may depend on your dmbs, though if they are ansi compatible they should support INFORMATION_SCHEMA) that start with `wp_wpsc_`.

(For instance for DB2:

```
SELECT NAME FROM TABLES WHERE NAME LIKE 'wp_wpsc_%'
```

)

Then iterate through that result set, and create a dynamic statement in the form you have given to read from the current table and insert into the corresponding new one.